# Open Activity with setPendingIntentTemplate

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I'm doing a widget with one stackView which i'm adding bitmaps(images) inside with a RemoteViewFactory.

My problem is when I want to do a `onClickPendingIntent()` for each image (that I have inside the stackView). I know I have to use `setPendingIntentTemplate()` instead, but I don't know how to go to an Activity when I press some widget's image.

Then this is what I have inside `onUpdate()` from widget class to create the Pending Intent Template:

```
Intent templateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, templateIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widget_stack_view,
                templatePendingIntent);
```

And this is what I have in a RemoteViewsFactory class to handle the Pending Intent Template:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int index){
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.grid_item_layout);

    rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, images.get(index).getImage());

    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, images.get(index).getTitle());
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.image, fillInIntent);


    return rv;

}
```

So far, this `fillInIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, images.get(index).getTitle());` is acting with the phone showing me a "use complete actions" where you can choose with which app you want to open, but if you see what i'm putting in the `putExtra()` is a String. But what I want is open a Activity and then pass with `putExtra()` a image (`images.get(index).getImage()`) that is a bitmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong:

```
Intent templateIntent = new Intent(context, Activity_I_want_to_open.class);
templateIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent templatePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context, 0, templateIntent, 0);
```

Then, I didn't need to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, because I want to updating nothing.

And in the RemoteViews side:

```
Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.image, fillInIntent);
```

I didn't need putExtra() because I'm not sending data to other activity.

Comment: yes, but I can not send data from fillInIntent to templateIntent?